# How to remove an element that appears more than once in a list without changing the length of the list (no sets)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've looked up many times and it seems that sets are the best option however for this assignment I believe it is not allowed. So, basically, I made an empty list and it generates a list that is 5 elements long with numbers between 1 and 9 inside. But all the numbers need to appear once in the list. How do I do that?

```
    import random
    lis = []
    for i in range(1,6):
        x = random.randint(1,9)
        lis.append(x)
```

I've tried,

```
    if x not in lis:
    lis.append(x)
```

But the length of my list kept changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, You can use a `while` alongside the `if` statement you were originally trying:

```
import random
lis = []
while len(lis) < 5:
    x = random.randint(1,9)
    if x not in lis:
        lis.append(x)

>>> lis
[2, 8, 1, 5, 3]
```

But if you want to be tricky about it, you can do:

```
x = list(range(1,10))
random.shuffle(x)
>>> x[:5]
[2, 1, 4, 3, 7]
```

Or

```
import numpy as np

>>> np.random.choice(range(1,10),5,replace=False)
array([7, 5, 3, 6, 4])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! The while loop helped, I guess the while loop was better than using a for loop in this case! Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this like Sacul said with a while loop, but here's another fancy option, it might not be allowed by your assignment though.

```
import random
lis = random.sample(range(1,10),5)
```

Comment: Oh yeah I see, I forgot to mention that the prof doesn't allow us to use the random.sample or random.shuffle. But thanks a lot!